# How to automate google api access token using ready api

Tags: groovy, gmail-api, access-token, ready-api

I have done the below steps.

1. Got client Id and Secret Id from manually from console.developer.google.com
2. Passed the above values by creating an auth profile in the ready api.
3. Got the access token manually from google apis.

The apis are functioning as expected, but I would like to get the access token automatically because the value which I got manually gets expired.

Comment: Please add the _code_ with what you have tried already and how it failed.

Comment: For me, I implemented my own DataStoreFactory that persists the DataStore to a database. Then I just passed that DataStoreFactory to GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow and it takes care of the refresh automatically for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow to generate the credential.

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(databaseDataStoreFactoryService)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build()
```

where "databaseDataStoreFactoryService" is a [DataStoreFactory](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/store/DataStoreFactory) that you provide to persist and retrieve the Google tokens somewhere.